# Error in App Delegate iOS 8 programming

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting an error in my app delegate file and I"m not sure what is causing it. The build succeeds but crash as soon as it opens and this is the message I get:

2015-01-07 10:31:20.043 Youth Xplosion[4386:672604] Could not load the "(null)" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.example.Youth-Xplosion"
2015-01-07 10:31:20.085 Youth Xplosion[4386:672604] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key day.'

I was messing around with my launch screen so I'm not sure if I messed up something there or somewheres else in my storyboard.

Here is my app delegate file:

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    let notification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

    let dateTime = NSDate()
    notification.fireDate = dateTime
    notification.alertBody = friday1


    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

    let notification1: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

    let dateTime1 = NSDate()
    notification1.fireDate = dateTime
    notification1.alertBody = saturday1


    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification1)
    */




}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


//Notification Messages
let friday1 = "First Service of YX 2015 begins in 1 hour!"
let friday2 = "First Service in 10 minutes!"

let saturday1 = "WAKE UP DEVOTIONS START IN 1 HOUR"
```

}

Comment: The message is telling you that you have a problem with your nib file. Have you correctly hooked up the IBOutlets?

Comment: Yea that was the issue. didn't compeltely remove one of my outlets. Thanks!